# Azure Pipelines - How to download artifacts from latest pipeline that successfully produced artifacts?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a build and release pipeline that runs the build stage after every pull request and the release stage on a schedule.

The build stage creates the artifacts and the release stage downloads them.

The problem I have is the download artifact task only seems to work if the current or previous pipeline produced them

E.g.

[image]

Should this be possible?

This is what I'm using to publish

```yaml
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(ArtifactPathToPublish)'
    artifact: '$(ArtifactName)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

And this is what I'm using to download

```yaml
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'a1acfe27-c376-4239-a45c-a77eddf71d6f'
    pipeline: 153
    runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'
    runBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
    allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
    artifact: '${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}'
    path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}'
```

I can't see any settings that may help with my issue.

At the moment it looks like I would need a hacky fix to find the `runId` of the last successful pipeline and stage that ran and produced an artifact

Comment: Hi @Konzy262, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I worked round it by using the REST API to query the build endpoint with a filter on 'individualCI' as the reason filter. I then plugged the id returned into the `runId` field of the existing `Download Pipeline Artifacts` task. Your solution looks fine as well although it's more powershell to maintain as you are downloading the artifact manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, we can download the specified artifact via the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.1-preview.5
```

Add task-Power shell and add the below script:

```
$outfile = "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\{artifact name}.zip"
$connectionToken="{pat}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

#Get download artifact url
$GetArtifactURL = "GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.1-preview.5"
$GetArtifactResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetArtifactURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get 

#download artifact zip file to outfile path
$DownloadArtifactURL = $GetArtifactResult.resource.downloadUrl
$DownloadArtifact = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $DownloadArtifactURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $outfile
```